# context.SaveChanges() works, but database is never updated? (MVC 3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've written a form in ASP.NET MVC3, and I can't get the entry to save the changes I make in the database, but while debugging, I noticed that the changes were reflected in the data context. I am experiencing no errors running this code. Let me know if you need more. Thanks!

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Tool tool, FormCollection collection)
    {
        if (collection["Tool.Person.PersonID"] != "")
        {
            tool.Person= context.People.Find(
                 Convert.ToInt32(collection["Tool.Person.PersonID"])
            );
        }
        if (collection["Tool.Company.CompanyID"] != "")
        {
            tool.Company = context.Companies.Find(
                 Convert.ToInt32(collection["Tool.Company.CompanyID"])
            );
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Entry(tool).State = EntityState.Modified; 
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(tool);
    }
```

The first two `if` statements are checking to see if the user inputted a person or company, and the information is passed via the FormCollection. PersonID and CompanyID are primary keys for Person and Company, respectively. I went through the method line by line multiple times and achieve the same result - after context.SaveChanges();, the  context reflects the changes, but the database entries remain null for both Person_PersonID and Company_CompanyID.

Comment: Why not just wreite a siple update linq statement

Comment: Maybe a dumb question on my part, but is your context wired up to the database?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think you can operate on `tool` like this after it's been passed back from the view (I haven't tried it, though).  I think you need to get a new `tool` from the database inside your action, and perform the updates against that `tool`.

Comment: @user1304444 - That was my fear...I've thought of removing the tool parameter completely, manually loading the tool from the context using the tool's primary key, and assigning each field from the FormCollection to the tool, but I'm trying to find a better way.

Comment: Just retrieve fresh data from the database there in your '[HttpPost]'  For example Tool tool = db.GetTool(ToolID).  Then perform your edits on that fresh data.  I highly recommend using a view model like I show in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a view model and accessing the database after the user submits the form.

This should get you well on your way.

ViewModel

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Project.ViewModels
{
    public class _tools
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage="ToolID is required")]
        public int32 ToolID{ get; set; } //whatever ID you use to retrieve the Tool from the database.

        [Required(ErrorMessage="PersonID is required")]
        public int32 PersonID{ get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="CompanyID is required")]
        public int32 CompanyID{ get; set; }
    }
```

}

Controller Post

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(_tool viewModel)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Tool tool = db.GetTool(viewModel.ToolID) //whatever method you use to get a current version of the row.  You already do this before you send the data to the client, so just copy that code

        tool.Person = viewModel.PersonID
        tool.Company = viewModel.CompanyID

        context.Entry(tool).State = EntityState.Modified; 
        context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(tool);
}
```

View

```
@model = _tool

@using(Html.BeginForm("Edit", "ControllerNameHere", FormMethod.Post, null))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ToolID)
    @*Also add whatever inputs you use to get PersonID and CompanyID from the user.
      Make sure to either use the @Html helpers or to give them names that correspond.
      i.e. name one input PersonID and the other CompanyID*@

    <input type="submit" value="Edit">

}
```

Comment: thanks :) never thought to pass the information in the viewmodel, good idea.